# ActiveRecord Relation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

def index

```
    @users = User.order("name").page(params[:page]).per_page(5)

end
```

This is my UsersController where i try to view all users from database. Problem is because is see only this error:

```
undefined method `page' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_User:0x000000044853d8>
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: which gem have you used for pagination?

Comment: ok sorry , i need to restart rails server to work with new gem ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this incase you have used will_paginate gem

```
@users = User.order("name ASC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

Take a look on the gem [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)

Answer (score 0):

The usage of [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) is slight different than `Kaminari`. You should do:

```
@users = User.order('name').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
```